# Robot Framework - Looking for a keyword like "Run Keyword And Return Log"

Tags: robotframework

I am working on a robot framework case in which I run a task. This task is not supposed to be fully executed when the user does not have the appropriate permissions. However, the setting is like this that the task still runs successfully in this case, hence there is no error message that could be used in "Run Keyword And Expect Error". However, the log under the keyword (with log level = Info) tells me "You do not have permission to do XYZ". So I would need to look for this string in the log.

It seems like a simple task, but I do not seem to be able to retrieve this info message as a variable.

I would like to do something similar to

```
*** Test Cases *** 

Check if user can execute task
    ${info_message}=   Run Keyword and Return Log    Run Task 123
    Should Contain    ${info_message}    You do not have permission
```

Does anyone know a way to retrieve this log as a variable that I could subsequently check for? Thanks!

Comment: your best shot (and probably easier) is to get that info from the http response using the library RESTinstance

Answer (score 1):

See if this solves your question (it could be simpler but then it would not be fun):

```py
*** Test Cases ***
Check if user can execute task
    ${info_message}    ${status}=    Run Keyword and Return Log    Run Task 123
    Should Contain    ${info_message}    You do not have permission
    # Positive call
    ${info_message}    ${status}=    Run Keyword and Return Log    Run Task 123    sudo    Make me a sandwich
    Should Contain    ${info_message}    Here is your nice sandwich, Sir! 

*** Keywords ***
Run Keyword and Return Log
    [Arguments]    @{keyword}
    ${status}    ${output}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Run Keyword    @{keyword}
    Log    ${status}
    ${return code}=    Set Variable If    "${status}" == "PASS"    0    -1
    [Return]    ${output}    ${return code}

Run Task 123
    [Arguments]    @{command}
    @{command}=    Create List    @{command}    'none'
    Log Many    @{command}
    ${output}=    Set Variable If    "${command[0]}" == "sudo"    Here is your nice sandwich, Sir! \nI did not add mayonaise, as usual.    You do not have permission to execute task 123
    [Return]    ${output}
```

Comment: Regretfully, this approach doesn't work with the logging of the target keyword as OP asks, but with its returned values.

Comment: But the real Run Task 123 would output the message to process, right?

Comment: It doesn't say that, while OP said in the question - "However, the log under the keyword (with log level = Info) tells me ", "So I would need to look for this string in the log."

Comment: Yes, Todor is right. My task does not output the message (then I could assign the output to a variable and work with this variable accordingly) but just shows the message I am looking for in the log. But thanks for the suggestion and an upvote for the nice sandwich =)

Comment: My confusion, is about the origin of the log. Is it from robotframework, a library or operating system? (not from a user keyword, because that would be easily fixed)

Comment: The log is coming from the software which I am testing with robotframework and which I cannot influence, unfortunately. The log is written back to the output.xml file.  I could try to parse this output.xml file but I think that's way too much for this task.

Comment: So how do you see that log? It must be written to stdout or stderr. How did the software under test being ran? Did you use Process or Operating System? If you can identify how that message goes to output.xml, you could try to intercept it (a copy).

Comment: @Florestan the log entry in the output.xml or the report file is not generated by the software you are testing, but from the library keyword that you use to communicate with it. As Helio wrote, share the library/keyword name that you use in order to get answer that fit your needs.